# Caesar's Cipher in C: can't seem to wrap around the latter letters of the alphabet

Tags: c, math, encryption, caesar-cipher

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char text[1000], alpha;
    int n;

    printf("Please type in text:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", text);

    printf("\nRotation number:  "); // rotates letters to the right.
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n");

    n = n % 26; // to wrap around alphabet.

    int i = 0;
    while (text[i] != '\0')
    {
        if((text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z'))
        {
            alpha = text[i];

            text[i] += n;
```

This is the part which I do not understand why it isn't working:

```
            if(text[i] > 'z')

            {
                text[i] = 'a' + (n - (26 % (alpha - 'a')));
            }
```

It works until the letter 'd'. 'f' just gives '\200'.

Any ideas as to why my code does not work?

```
        }
        i++;
    }

        printf("Encrypted text:\n%s", text);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you do it this way? Why don't you use `islower()`? So many questions...

Comment: I'm still learning to code in C and thus I prefer to write all the code myself without the use of existing functions.

Comment: I don't understand it works correctly. Then what is  problem.

Comment: It does not work correctly. When n = 6, z should = f 
however, I get \200 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
text[i] = (text[i] - 'a' + n) % 26 + 'a';
```

which does this

```
text[i] - 'a'  // converts text[i] to a number between 0 and 25
+ n            // add the cipher value
% 26           // wrap as necessary so the value is between 0 and 25
+ 'a'          // convert back to a letter between 'a' and 'z'
```

So the loop should look like this

```
for ( int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++ )
{
   if ( text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z' )
      text[i] = (text[i] - 'a' + n) % 26 + 'a';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, when I used your code, I get this:

Please type in text:
x y z

Rotation number:  2

Encrypted text:
z c d

It should be z a b

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help. Can you please explain why your previous answer didn't work yet this one did? Thanks again.

Comment: @HeshamSaleh You didn't remove the line `test[i] += n` from your code, so you were adding `n` twice.

Answer (score 1):

This part which you do not understand why is not working:

```
if(text[i] > 'z')
{
    text[i] = 'a' + (n - (26 % (alpha - 'a')));
}
```

would be simply solved with

```
if(text[i] > 'z')
{
    text[i] -= 26;
}
```

**UPDATE** you are working with `char` whick is probably signed, so adding the cipher, say, 20 to `z` will produce a number that is > 128, ie negative.

I suggest this amendment

```
int alpha;   // changed from char

//...

alpha = text[i] + n;
if (alpha > 'z')
    alpha -= 26;
text[i] = alpha;
```

Comment: Man, I was just going to post something like this, with the caveat that `n` might be larger than 26.

Comment: @EOF and I was about to add the rider that the lead-up to this might overcomplicate my answer.

Comment: I just saw the `n %= 26` in the original question, so it's all good.

Comment: @WeatherVane but Sir it is not working. Giving same as pervious output.

Comment: Still does not work if n is equal to 6 or higher. maybe the problem is in a different area of the code? I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: That is because you are using `char` which is probably `signed`. Change `char alpha` to `int alpha`, and check its range *before* assigning its value to the string.

Comment: Yes, `z` is 122 decimal, so `test[i] += n` results in integer overflow and undefined behavior if `test[i]` is `z` and `n` is 6.